# Derivation of an integral identity from the kdv equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The stationary KdV equation given by

\begin{equation}
6u(x)u_{x}−u_{xxx}=0 \quad \quad \quad(1)
\end{equation}

It has a solution given by
$$\bar{u}(x)=−2\mathrm{sech}^{2}(x)+\frac{2}{3} \quad \quad \quad (2)$$

This solution obeys the identity
 $$\int_{0}^{z}{\left(\bar{u}(y)−\frac{2}{3}\right)\int_{0}^{y}{\left(\bar{u}(x)−\frac{2}{3}\right)dxdy}}=\bar{u}(z)+\frac{4}{3} \quad \quad \quad (3)$$

Is it possible to derive this kind of identity without using the explicit form of the solution $\bar{u}(x)$? That is only by using the fact that $\bar{u}(x)$ is a solution to (1). I tried differentiating (3) thrice on the left side but that generates a lot of different terms for which it is hard to use (1) to simplify.

Thank you in advance